# http request post username and password wih header to get auth/key in R

Tags: r, httprequest, httpresponse

Can I get recommendation to learn http request post username and password with header to get auth/key in R?. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Examples* section of `httr`'s [GET function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.0/topics/GET) is useful.

There is one example which demonstrates how to add headers...

```
GET(url, add_headers(a = 1, b = 2))
```

...and another which shows how to authenticate...

```
GET(url, authenticate("username", "password"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place for a quick start is vignette of `httr` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html

The POST request is covered in `POST()` function; the exact implementation & next steps would depend on your use case.