# HTTP POST request using R httr2 package

Tags: r, httr, httr2

For a project I need to access data from the Global Forest Watch (GFW), using its AP. I first need to obtain a token through a POST request.

[The GFW indicates the following request :](https://www.globalforestwatch.org/help/developers/guides/create-and-use-an-api-key/)

> curl --location --request POST 'https://data-api.globalforestwatch.org/auth/token' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ --data-urlencode 'username=<YOUR_USERNAME>' \ --data-urlencode 'password=<YOUR_PASSWORD>'

As I will process the data in R, I want to obtain this token using R functions.

I tried to use the httr2 package to run this request  :

```
req_token = request('https://data-api.globalforestwatch.org/auth/token') %>%
  req_headers("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") %>% 
  req_body_json(list(username = "username", password = "password")) 
resp_token = req_perform(req_token)
```

However it returns HTTP 422 error. I have the feeling it is related to the format of the body, not adapted to the "data-urlencode".

I have also tried using httr package, by providing my password and username in a body or through `httr:::authenticate()` (in comment here).

```
url = "https://data-api.globalforestwatch.org/auth/token"
custom_headers = c("Content-Type" =  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
data = list(username = "username", password = "password")
username = "username"
password = "password"
resp = httr::POST(url, 
                  body = data, 
                  add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
                  #authenticate(username, password, type = "basic"))
```

Again, this does not work. `resp` returns failed status, with message "field required" of type "value_error.missing" for username and password.

It might be a silly question, but I am quite new to API requests in R.

Comment: Look at [How to call API in R with a token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60262937/10489562) and [HTTR POST in r token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65389851/10489562) and [http request post username and password wih header to get auth/key in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54627444/10489562).

Comment: If the content type is 'x-www-form-urlencoded' then you need to have the body be  form data. Try using `req_body_form` instead of `req_body_json`